# Apache + PHP FPM - Ensuring no vulnerability left unchecked

Tags: php, apache, fastcgi

I finished setting up FPM/FastCGI to work with apache2 as described in the accepted solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/378734/how-to-configure-apache-to-run-php-as-fastcgi-on-ubuntu-12-04-via-terminal

And I did a further research to ensure that no vulnerability left open, and I ended up in the PHP Docs:

http://php.net/manual/en/security.cgi-bin.attacks.php

The first pinpoint they've wrote literally spawn a big red exclamation point on my head, and I had to open a discussion about it right here.

Questions:

- Will the first provided possible attack work with the setup we did by following the accepted answer ?
- Is there an option to monitor php5-fpm processes in order to know which scripts are being executed ?
- Will the previous php.ini located in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini will still be functional and not just disregarded when using PHP FPM/FastCGI
- Any other precautions ?